# Is Android Studio ready for production?

Tags: android, android-studio

I know Android Studio is at its early access stage. Is it ready for production at all? Does anyone know and has anyone deploy an app from Android Studio?

Comment: It's not that bad, but it's clearly a super-early release.

Comment: I use it for production, but with Ant instead of Gradle. I moved over from IntelliJ so for me it is working pretty much the same as before - slightly better actually, due to some of the additions. A whole lot of the issues seems to be related to the new build system, instead of the IDE.

Comment: In my opinion, nope. I installed Android Studio for a test, but I returned to Eclipse with ADT in a day. There are not few "unexpected" bugs in the integration part. (ex: layout editor, resource management, ...)

Comment: It's alpha, yes, but its based on a fairly stable intellij 13 so useable, but has bugs. But mind you they have a around 2 weeks update cycle so things move fast.So if you start your porject now chances are that halfway through the first RC will be there.

Comment: A year after my first look at AS I am giving it another try with 0.8.6 and things are looking good. Considering Ecplipse always gave me a headache anyways Studio is looking good and it will only get better from here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it is not. In fact it is available as an alpha release.

As the Android Team report on its website

> Caution: Android Studio is currently available as an early access
>   preview. Several features are either incomplete or not yet implemented
>   and you may encounter bugs. If you are not comfortable using an
>   unfinished product, you may want to instead download (or continue to
>   use) the ADT Bundle (Eclipse with the ADT Plugin).

[Here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) is the link to the first Beta release of [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html).

Comment: Any idea about release date of production?

Comment: @android.h Unfortunately there is no one. Neither theirs roadmap is really clear

Comment: Maybe they will announce it in [preview channel](http://tools.android.com/preview-channel). I will need more patience :)

Comment: I think an update from Google is overdue.

Comment: Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.0 got released today!

Comment: @sdeff can you share a link ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: And it's still not ready.

Answer (score 2):

Why not Intelij IDEA?

I worked in a team (me and another guy) with Android Studio on an app. We had some ups and downs with it due to the bouncy nature of an early access preview something something but nothing really bad.
Still, I think it is adventurous and a bit irresponsible to work with an early access preview IDE in production environment so I'd recommend using Intelij IDEA for android development. It is a matured and stabled product, and it has many great advantages over eclipse that makes life much easier.

I also worked with eclipse on a commercial app and this highly praised IDE had so many bugs I can't wait for Android Studio to come out, and for now I use Intelij IDEA which saved me when eclipse filed to build the project for days.

Down goes eclipse.

Comment: Is the community(Free) version good enough? Or you have to get the paid version. If you need the paid version for android app development, then there is no point to download it because android studio will eventually come out.

Comment: never used the paid version. Only the community, and it's definitely good enough for Android developing, more than eclipse.