# Is it OK to use Android Studio for production? (License concern)

Tags: android, ide, android-studio

I'm currently developing an app using Eclipse + ADT Plugin and I want to start using Android Studio. I don't mind dealing with a few bugs and similar problems; I have already tried it and it seems fine. But as far as the license concern, may I use it for a production application?

I already saw this post: [Is Android Studio ready for production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758468/is-android-studio-ready-for-production)
But the answer there says it's not ready because it lacks features and it's still in alpha. I don't mind using an "unfinished product", but want to ensure that I'm not going to violate the license agreement.

Comment: I think the question was answered in the link you provided. If you want to use an unfinished product, go ahead, but be aware that if you have a deadline and an update to AS broke something it may be harder to find a workaround.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition is completely free and open-source, licensed under the Apache 2 license and can be used for any kind of development. Android Studio has the same licensing terms.
>   http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/#comment-4939

Comment: He said "I don't mind for a few bugs... But as far as the license concern, may I use it for a production application?" and I think I answer it. I think the title of the question is a bit misleading, but what he ask is licence concern. I don't really understand why my answer is so down-voted :Q

Comment: You're correct. I had missed his mention of licensing as well. Good call.

Comment: Is there some official document, for instance from Google, which would explicitly state that Android Studio is free for commercial use?

Comment: @AlexSee I was looking for the same. My answer is the best that I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Given that Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition...

And [IntelliJ is licensed under Apache 2.0](http://www.jetbrains.org/display/IJOS/License+Information)...

Then the file https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/idea/+/master/NOTICE.txt from the Android Studio source *may* help with any license concerns.

```
This software includes code from IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
Copyright (C) JetBrains s.r.o.
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/
```