# Is the sylius ready for production?

Tags: sylius

At [Sylius](http://sylius.org/) "Sylius is still in development" is shown at the top. Does it mean that I can not use Sylius for my future shop? Or there could be bugs in the current version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Android Studio ready for production?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758468/is-android-studio-ready-for-production)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your release date.

V1.0.0-beta will be released by the end of November (see [Roadmap update](http://sylius.org/blog/sylius-roadmap-update))

There are a lot refactoring and a big focus on documentation.

Some companies are already using it, you can see them in the showcase of official website, and personnaly, i use it for my future shop.